# Is there a way to obtain Shiny Mewtwo in Let's Go without repeatedly reloading save files?

Tags: pokemon-lets-go

In Let's Go, it seems that, as far as I know, Mewtwo is the only Pokémon that does not respawn (the legendary birds can be found in the wild).

Since Mewtwo does not respawn, is there any way to obtain Shiny Mewtwo in Let's Go without reloading a save file hundreds/thousands of times, or is reloading a save file hundreds/thousands of times the only way to obtain it?

Note: In the future, it will be possible to transfer a Shiny Mewtwo from Pokémon Go to Let's Go. I'm specifically asking this question in the context of Let's Go itself.

Answer (score -1):

a shiny! and that even a mewtwo! you need to be lucky- these are some figures for 'lets-go' series- **1;4096** but theres an item in lets-go called *shiny charm* (**YOU HAVE TO COMPLETE YOUR POKEDEX**) which decreases the odds to **1;1365** and use *lures* to boost the chances. At the best of your luck sometimes the odds can even be- **1;273.076**. And sorry, but you have to reload.

Comment: There's actually a really good answer hiding in here that would provide a lot of extra details about getting a shiny Mewtwo. But it's all info that's a tangent to the actual question being asked, and tough to see unless one is already familiar with the odds being mentioned here.